# read a dict into self

Tags: python, class, dictionary, pickle

I have a class that is doing a lot of stuff. In the end, it saves everything into a pickle. When I rerun this class I want to read the pickle instead of doing everything again. Unfortunately it the variable is always empty if I unpickle. Why is that so?

```
import pandas as pd

class Test:
    def __init__(path, value):
        # path points to a .txt file but its in the same folder as the pickle
        data_path, data = os.path.split(path)
        pickle_path = os.path.join(data_path, name.split('.')[1] + '.pickle'
        if os.path.isfile(pickle_path):
            self = pd.read_pickle(path)
        else:
            # do a ton of stuff and safe it as pickle afterwards

variable = Test(path, value)
```

In this case variable is empty if I read from pickle but correct if I do all the stuff...

Comment: What do you expect `self = something` to do? What do you mean the variable is empty?

Comment: The first parameter of your constructor is the instance, so `in path` or `read_pickle(path)` is not doing what you expect, and explains why things are empty

Comment: I hope my edit makes it a bit clearer. Actually I'm saving the class object in the end. So when I read it it looks like a dict. when I check it in the class its still like I want it. but when its done with the init and should return the object information into **variable** variable looks like the object it should be but its empty.

Comment: ``self`` is not a magic variable. Assigning to ``self`` does not change the object, it merely changes the local variable ``self`` to point to whatever you assigned. You *cannot* replace the instance in a method, you can only change its internal state.

Comment: Be aware the proper design is to have a function which *either* constructs a new ``Test`` *or* loads an existing ``Test``. By the time ``__init__`` is called, a new ``Test`` has already been created – you cannot even get rid of it at that point.

Comment: So from your comments I guess I have to eigther go into the class and create the object or read it from pickle file but not going into the class and read it there... Is it correct?

Comment: You can also overload ``__new__`` to do this. However, ``__new__`` is uncommon and many people (likely including future you) will have trouble maintaining such code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I want to cache some calculation results I will load/dump the object outside the class, something like,

```py
pickle_path = os.path.join(data_path, name.split('.')[1] + '.pickle'
if os.path.isfile(pickle_path):
    with open(pickle_path, 'rb') as f:
        variable = pickle.load(f)  # use cached results
else:
    variable = Test()  # do all the calculations
```

Comment: The potential issue with this is that the class might change, causing troubles when loading a previously dumped objects. You may also consider saving the calculation results as json files and write a save/load methods in the class. Good luck.

Comment: That's okay, actually, I have a flag, and when it's true it will do all the steps again and overwrite the old pickle. So if something changes I just set this flag true.